# Using 3rd party "charts",the response values as double.How it make to integer format?

Tags: ios, swift, charts

Using third party "charts".the input format of values are Double and response also in double.For example, my input is `a=12,b=13,c=20,d=25` when it comes in graph showing like `a=12.0,b=13.0,c=20.0,d=25.0`

[image: I want get values as, 12,13,20,25]

here is my code

```
func updateChartData()  {

    let skipped = 12
    let correct = 13
    let wrong = 20
    let timedOut = 25

     let track = ["Skipped", "Right", "Wrong", "Not Attended"]
     let money = [skipped, correct, wrong, timedOut]

     var entries = [PieChartDataEntry]()
     for (index, value) in money.enumerated() {
         let entry = PieChartDataEntry()
         entry.y = Double(value)
         entry.label = track[index]
         entries.append( entry)
     }

     // 3. chart setup
     let set = PieChartDataSet( values: entries, label: "Pie Chart")
     // this is custom extension method. Download the code for more details.
     var colors: [UIColor] = []

     for _ in 0..<money.count {
         let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
         let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
         let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
         let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
         colors.append(color)
     }
     set.colors = colors
     let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)
     viewPieCharts.data = data
     viewPieCharts.noDataText = "No data available"
     // user interaction
     viewPieCharts.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

     let d = Description()
     d.text = "iOSCharts.io"
     viewPieCharts.chartDescription = d
     viewPieCharts.centerText = "Pie Chart"
     viewPieCharts.holeRadiusPercent = 0.5
     viewPieCharts.transparentCircleColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

> I want the values without decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert this code

```
let format = NumberFormatter()
format.numberStyle = .none
let formatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: format)
data.setValueFormatter(formatter)
```

after

```
let data = PieChartData(dataSet: set)
```

Comment: @mag_zbc, NumberFormatter is a child of the Formatter and Formatter conforms to IValueFormatter protocol.

Comment: Yes, `DefaultValueFormatter` is a subclass of `IValueFormatter` and has a constructor that takes `NumberFormatter` parameter

Comment: Yah... Worked for me .. @V.Khambir

Answer (score -1):

Override `IValueFormatter` and set it to your `PieChartData` instance

```
class MyValueFormatter : IValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double,
                        entry: ChartDataEntry,
                        dataSetIndex: Int,
                        viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        return String(format: "%.0f", value)
    }
}


data.setValueFormatter(MyValueFormatter())
```